# NGINX proxy_pass to dynamic port

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm hoping someone can help me with this.
I'm looking to proxy pass something like this:

```
http://storage.domainname.com:port
```

to this:

```
http://192.168.12.10:port
```

My problem is that the port is dynamic, and it's not feasible for me to write dozens of `location` blocks for it.

This is my conf (I'm using port 61788 for testing):

```
server {
    listen 61788;

    server_name storage.*;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        set $upstream_app 192.168.12.10;
        set $upstream_proto http;
        proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:61788;
    }
}
```

I don't think using location regex is applicable here, as the port is specified in the host. I've tried using `$remote_host` in `proxy_pass`, but that gave me a bad gateway error. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The port number that received the original request should be `$server_port`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to use `$server_port` instead or `$remote_port`!